# OS X Screen Mirroring Driver file

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, mirroring

With iOS 8 and OS X Yosemite, the ability of mirroring the iOS screen to the Desktop via USB was introduced.

I need to be able to physically access the Driver used to communicate the mirroring payload (copy the file to another computer).

I am more of a Windows kind of developer: How can I locate the Driver file to copy (if any)?

Comment: Do you want to access the Driver of OS X from within the iOS device ?

Comment: I need access to the driver on the OS-X machine ( eg. Yosemite ) so I could reverse-engineer the mirroring protocol

Comment: I am sorry sir, but why would you do it? I mean if you just want to draw on the mac's screen you can do it from within your app: please refer to UIScreen Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/

If this is not why you want to do -> and i just annoying you so I am sorry :-)
- Peace

Comment: UIScreen will not enable you to get SpringBoard messages and other UI widgets since these are running on a different process ( not under the app sand-box ), in addition, screen mirroring the iOS device also include Audio which is essential for my use-case

Comment: Now I got you :-) seems like you are working on a very interesting project!

Answer (score 0):

Found it at

> /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/iOSScreenCapture.plugin